# How to add a file to a github repository with deep tree of folders?

Tags: git, github

How to add a file to a github.com repository with deep tree of folders ?

Can we do this in any other way?

Cloning into after fork:

```
C:\>git clone https://github.com/orynider/premod.git
Cloning into 'premod'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9599, done.
Receiving objects:  98% (9408/9599), 3.71 MiB | 2.47 MiB/s remote: Total 9599 (d
Receiving objects:  99% (9504/9599), 3.71 MiB
Receiving objects: 100% (9599/9599), 5.08 MiB | 2.47 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6413/6413), done.
Checking out files: 100% (1417/1417), done.

C:\>git add .
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

C:\>cd premod

C:\premod>git add .

C:\premod>git commit -m"Adding phpBB Area-51 Favicon.ICO"
[3.0.x 034bf53] Adding phpBB Area-51 Favicon.ICO
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 premod/root/favicon.ico

C:\premod>git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/orynider/premod.git'

C:\premod>git pull origin master
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master

C:\premod>git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter the directory of the project you just cloned:

```
cd premod
```

Then you use any git commands.

Edit 1:

Regarding your second problem, the project doesn’t have a master branch.
Check the branches available and write it’s name while pushing or pulling.

Comment: I did that, look above: C:\>cd premod

C:\premod>git add .

Comment: Then is C:\premod>git pull origin 3.0.x ;)